# Extract app name from app-store:// and intent:// links

Tags: google-play-store

From time to time i encounter in links such as:

> android-app://com.sudaytoz.kakao.wbb/stzkakaowbb/sundaytoz

and i want to understand what is their play.google name
the previous example answer is:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sundaytoz.kakao.wbb

is it always like this? I guess i don't really get the "android-app://" prefix.

Same goes for links like:

> intent://adjust_reftag=c7L1pVanNIjjt#Intent;scheme=yandextaxi;package=ru.yandex.taxi;end

Answer (score 0):

The application ID is essentially a regular Java package name that follows these 3 rules:

```
1.It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).
2.Each segment must start with a letter.
3.All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].
```

As you can see in your links, the URL on Google Play contains the application ID.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id